# How to monitor sensor usage by an app in the background in Android?

Tags: android

The same way the android system tells about an app is using the GPS in the background.
How can I programmatically have an app that tells me that another app(s) other than mine is using the microphone or gyroscope for example?
The purpose of the App is to present to the user some statistics about the usage of the sensor by background apps/services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: you cannot without root.

> You could write an app to try and monitor what's happening on the
>   device, but it would require elevated permissions for your app like
>   running as System or requesting a large set of permissions, so that
>   you could query the appropriate services and access system resources
>   to guess at what other apps are doing. The packagemanager exposes api
>   calls for determining the installed applications and even examining
>   their permissions, At best though like mentioned in the earlier answer
>   all apps run in their own instance of the dalvik vm.

Source:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40284/how-can-i-detect-which-background-application-is-using-the-camera-microphone-or